# Trouble using "virt-install" on ubuntu to create VM, just hangs after displaying initial info

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04

I'm on an Ubuntu 14.04 box, and I need to create a VM using "virt-install".  I would have liked to use "virt-manager", but I only have ssh shell access.  I consulted various resources for how to create the disk image and the the "virt-install" command line.  I finally constructed what I thought was a valid command, but after submitting it, virt-install emitted just a couple of lines of output and then just essentially hung, not doing anything.  I've been watching it for ~30 minutes or so now, and nothing appears to have happened.  I tried viewing the environment from another shell, but I don't know how to tell if it's doing anything.

Here's what I've done so far.

I created a disk image with this (all with sudo):

```
fallocate -l 200g /var/lib/libvirt/images/jumphost.img
```

This returned quickly and appeared to allocate a disk image.

Here's my "virt-install" command line, and the entire output:

```
attuser@bl12-kvm-nest:/var/lib/libvirt/images$ sudo virt-install -r 24576 -n opnfv-arno-foreman -f /var/lib/libvirt/images/jumphost.img --cdrom=~/arno.2015.1.0.foreman.iso
ERROR    Error validating install location: Checking installer location failed: Could not find media '~/arno.2015.1.0.foreman.iso'.
attuser@bl12-kvm-nest:/var/lib/libvirt/images$ sudo virt-install -r 24576 -n opnfv-arno-foreman -f /var/lib/libvirt/images/jumphost.img --cdrom=$HOME/arno.2015.1.0.foreman.iso

Starting install...
Creating domain...                                           |    0 B     00:00
Connected to domain opnfv-arno-foreman
Escape character is ^]
```

The last two lines makes it seem like it's waiting for input from me, but I don't know why.

Comment: On a separate terminal run `netstat -lnt|grep :59`. If you see ports like `:59XX`, use vncviewer to connect to it. Your installation is running in graphical mode. If you want unattended installation, try using kickstart.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I'll try that in the morning. Can you elaborate on "kickstart"?

Comment: I found https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/libvirt.html , which I'm going to read through.  I tried doing "virsh list --all", and it showed the VM I tried to create, in a "shut off" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what's happening here is that virt-install has created the VM, and it's trying to do something to display information about the VM, perhaps in a graphical view.

I've moved past this (hopefully), as I can now run "virt-manager" over a VNC connection so I can use a GUI to manage my VMs.